# Disk-full conflict in Azure when deploying Functions by ARM template

Tags: azure-functions, azure-resource-manager, azure-app-service-plans, azure-deployment, azure-storage-account

Me and my team usually deploys Azure Functions Apps to the cloud by ARM templates. But these days, we was running that ARM template to create a new function and link it with the App Service Plan already created, when this message was thrown:

> {
> "status": "Failed",
> "error": {
> "code": "Conflict",
> "message": "Creating the site failed with a disk-full error. The storage quota might have been exceeded.",
> "details": [
> {
> "message": "Creating the site failed with a disk-full error. The storage quota might have been exceeded."
> },
> {
> "code": "Conflict"
> },
> {}
> ]
> } }

We search for the quotas in the platform and don't seem we have exceeded anything. We work with one App Service Plan, for 35 Azure Functions. The App Service is based on Dynamic Tier Y1 (If anyone knows about that too and could explain, I will really appreciate :-)).

We are in doubt because we have other resource groups which already contains the same architecture and even more functions linked to the same App Service Plan, but we could add more functions without problems. To resolve the problem for now, we deleted the app service plan and recreate it, together with all the functions, and it is running. However, does anyone know why this conflict message was thrown?

More information:

-> App Service Plan ARM template:

```
{
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
      "name": "[variables('servicePlan_name')]",
      "location": "[parameters('service_location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Y1",
        "tier": "Dynamic",
        "size": "Y1",
        "family": "Y",
        "capacity": 0
      },
      "kind": "functionapp",
      "properties": {
        "perSiteScaling": false,
        "maximumElasticWorkerCount": 1,
        "isSpot": false,
        "reserved": false,
        "isXenon": false,
        "hyperV": false,
        "targetWorkerCount": 0,
        "targetWorkerSizeId": 0
      }
    }
```

Comment: According to the error, you do not have enough storage space : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c3eafdbf-efff-482c-bee9-c8b5bb7d6f47/why-are-some-of-my-sites-unable-to-deploy?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Answer (score 1):

Please increase the size of the Azure Storage Account your Function App uses to see if that resolves the error. More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale).